# iOS: core data to many relationship

Tags: ios, json, core-data, nsarray

I have a doubt how to manage a "to many relationship" in core data.
In my example I have the main identity 'Struct' that have a "to many relationship" with another identity called 'Id_loc'
Then, I have this object in a JSON file that is a Struct identity:

```
{"id":"s1",
"n":"Name Struct",
"id_loc":["l1","l2"]} //id_loc can contain many element
```

when I parse this object I have id_loc as an array.

Inside Struct class I have two methods:

```
- (void)addLocObject:(Id_loc *)value;
- (void)addLoc:(NSSet *)values;
```

then I do this to store id_loc array inside:

```
   Struct *struct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Struct" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSArray *array_loc = [element objectForKey:@"id_loc"];
    NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:array_loc];
    [struct addLoc:set];
```

Is it a right way?

Is it not necessary to call this?

```
Id_loc *loc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Id_loc" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

**EDIT**

Is it the right answer?

```
    Struct *struct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Struct" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSArray *array_loc = [element objectForKey:@"id_loc"];
    for (id loc in array_loc){
        Id_loc *loc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Id_loc" inManagedObjectContext:context];
loc.ident = loc;
          [struct addLocObject:loc];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really save an NSSet into the CoreData just like that. NSSet contains other CoreData entities only which are related to your main object.

To save an array with data you need to use NSData property and use NSKeyedArchiver to archive your NSArray with NSStrings.

However even it's simplest solution there are some limitations. For example you won't be able to use and predicates on those properties. Therefore I would recommend to make another entity which is "Location" and create a location objects based on those "l1", "l2" values.

Yes you use addLocObject: or if you want to add multiple ones you use - (void)addLoc:(NSSet *)values; But you have to create those objects - create them in core data withing your context and than add it to main object.

Probably if you have ID you want also to select first existing locations and create them only if the don't exist.

Comment: yeah, I have an identity for Location called "Id_loc", and what's the way to add array_loc element to structure if I have this entity?

Comment: Do I use a loop and do "addLocObject"?

Comment: ah ok, then I should create the object and don't store the nsarry directly, I edit my question, can you check it?

Comment: Yes that sounds about right. Still I think what you want to have is to first check if Location with given ID exists , and use existing objects when it does.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking only about first populating, the in a second moment I check directly if exist or not the Struct in the new JSON file, and if the Struct don't exist I delete it directly. I also set the relation in "cascade" type so, when I delete struct also Id_loc associated are deleted. 
(another information about your issue: a Struct can have ever the same array array_loc, it can't change its element, but thank you anyway for the suggest)